# 404 error when polling Reddit's developer API

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I am trying to use Reddit's developer API to build a simple scraper that grabs posts and their replies in a target subreddit and produces JSON with the information.

I am getting a 404 error that I don't understand.

This is my code:

```
import praw
import json

def scrape(subreddit, limit):
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='Reddit data organizer 1.0 by /u/reallymemorable', client_id='none of your business', client_secret='none of your business')
    submissions = r.subreddit(subreddit).get_hot(limit=limit)
    for submission in submissions:
        data = {}
        data['title'] = submission.title
        data['score'] = submission.score
        data['url'] = submission.url
        data['author'] = str(submission.author)
        data['subreddit'] = str(submission.subreddit)
        data['num_comments'] = submission.num_comments
        data['over_18'] = submission.over_18
        data['selftext'] = submission.selftext
        data['is_self'] = submission.is_self
        data['name'] = submission.name
        data['created_utc'] = submission.created_utc
        data['permalink'] = submission.permalink
        data['domain'] = submission.domain
        data['id'] = submission.id
        data['kind'] = submission.kind
        json.dumps(data)

scrape('https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/', 25)
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
reallymemorable@Christians-MBP Desktop % python3 fetch-data-subreddit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reallymemorable/Desktop/fetch-data-subreddit.py", line 26, in <module>
    scrape('https://www.reddit.com/r/augmentedreality/comments/yv7sn8/ar_maximum_distance/', 25)
  File "/Users/reallymemorable/Desktop/fetch-data-subreddit.py", line 6, in scrape
    submissions = r.subreddit(subreddit).get_hot(limit=limit)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 583, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 580, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/util/deprecate_args.py", line 43, in wrapped
    return func(**dict(zip(_old_args, args)), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 941, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 330, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 266, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.NotFound: received 404 HTTP response
```

Comment: btw, you can set values like  `json.dumps({'title':  submission.title, ... }` rather than repeat `data[key] = value`

Comment: @OneCricketeer - thanks...dumb question: how would i then modify the print statement? do i have to wrap my big multi-line json dump in a print() statement?

Comment: I see no print statement in this code? But `data = { ... }; print(data)` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.subreddit(subreddit)` - `subreddit` should just be the name of the subreddit e.g. "funny" and not the full URL.

See the docs here: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/quick_start.html#obtain-a-subreddit